# Create an Icon with First and Last name first letter inside Icon in React native

Tags: react-native

I want to create an Icon with First name and Last name first letter inside an icon in react native. Please let me know how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple component like below, this will place the text in the middle, I have passed the initials as props but you can modify it to take color and other properties.

```
const InitialIcon = ({ initials }) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 30,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
      }}>
      <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 25 }}>{initials}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Usage

```
 <InitialIcon initials="AB" />
```